# Searching data in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to implement elastic search into my application. Currently i have a scenario where i need to search based on some search value.
Here is my implementation
**Mapping**

```
PUT /freelancer_working_days
{
  "mappings":{
    "properties":{
      "id": {"type": "text"},
      "freelancer_id": {"type": "text"},
      "working_days": {"type": "text"}, 
      "working_time": {"type":"keyword"}
    }
  }
}
```

A Document that i inserted

```
PUT /freelancer_working_days/_doc/1
{
  "id": "1",
  "freelancer_id":"abc-215-aysg-uyt-",
  "working_days":"{{\"days\":[1,4,3,5,7],\"time\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12}}",
  "working_time":"{\"1\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12},\"3\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12},\"4\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12},\"5\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12},\"7\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12}}"
}
```

Now what am i trying to get is that based on working time i get this document back so i am trying this but it gives me 0 hits. What am i doing wrong?

```
GET /freelancer_working_days/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "working_time": "12"
    }
  }
}
```

If i analyze with default values like this

```
GET /freelancer_working_days/_analyze
{
  "text": ["{\"1\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12},\"3\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12},\"4\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12},\"5\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12},\"7\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12}}"],
}
```

I get tokens like :

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "1",
      "start_offset" : 2,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "to",
      "start_offset" : 7,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "7",
      "start_offset" : 11,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    ...
    {
      "token" : "12",
      "start_offset" : 112,
      "end_offset" : 114,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 24
    }
  ]
```

Comment: You're searching in the query by "working_days", not "working_times". What do you want to find?

Comment: Sorry for that a mistake actually am trying to find documents based on working_time.
Example : ```"working_time": "9" ```

Answer (score 1):

Your working_time field is defined with type `keyword`, and the `keyword` analyzer [is a noop analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current//analysis-keyword-analyzer.html), which mean your entire working_time string

> {"1":{"to":7,"from":12},"3":{"to":7,"from":12},"4":{"to":7,"from":12},"5":{"to":7,"from":12},"7":{"to":7,"from":12}}

has been indexed as a single token string, and that's reason why your term query with value "12" does not match with it.

Testing it with the `_analyze` [API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-analyze.html) on your `freelancer_working_days` index

```
GET /freelancer_working_days/_analyze
{
  "field": "working_time",
  "text": "{\"1\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12},\"3\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12},\"4\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12},\"5\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12},\"7\":{\"to\":7,\"from\":12}}"
}
```

will give

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : """{"1":{"to":7,"from":12},"3":{"to":7,"from":12},"4":{"to":7,"from":12},"5":{"to":7,"from":12},"7":{"to":7,"from":12}}""",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 116,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

*Reference*: [Keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current//analysis-keyword-analyzer.html)

If you need a full text search, consider to change the type of `working_time` field to `text`

Comment: No i need to use keyword for matching the exact times. so term query needs to be used.

Comment: can you suggest some analyzer which i could use

Comment: @new_programmer I don't quite get the purpose why you store the whole working time as json escaped string like that? What is your expected result with the query `"working_time": "12"`?

Comment: I am saving it from the postgres database that's why the string is getting escaped. I am storing it as this to make it searchable using es. Is there any other good option how i can save this in my database.

Comment: why not something like https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/range.html